# How I find the distributed protocol it is using in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

RabbitMQ support two distributed protocols, one is "mirrored queues", the other is "quorum queues".

How I find the distributed protocol it is using in RabbitMQ?

Can I get it by CLIs in RabbitMQ,such as rabbitmqctl/rabbitmq-diagnostics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is defined at queue level.

So you need to check the queues information.

If using [rabbimtqctl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#type%7E2), you should check list_queues and specifically the queue type (classic or quorum).
If classic queue, check arguments for replication information